# How to prevent duplicate Dynamics CRM plug-in steps

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-365

When deploying plugins using the Visual Studio Microsoft Dynamics 365 Developer Toolkit, we have been plagued with duplicate steps being created.

[image]

If we find a duplicate step has been created, we delete the plugin from the server and then redeploy the plugin from Visual Studio using the right click, deploy method.
The RegisterFile.crmregister is under source control so the guids should be maintained whichever member of our small team deploys.

Why are the duplicate plugin steps being created and how can it be prevented in a team situation?

Comment: Please double check your solution first, you might already have the duplicate steps there.